# Enable/disable Ajax Combobox doesn't work the first time, works the second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, combobox

This is similar to a recent post of mine, but since I solved part of my problem, I'm re-posting this as a separate issue. I have an ASP.Net application with an Ajax ComboBox. When a dropdownlist's OnSelectedIndexChanged event is fired, the server-side method FindEmpInfo is called. FindEmpInfo does some stuff and then calls the method EnableDeviceInfo. So, like this:

```
protected void FindEmpInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeviceInfo = findEmpInfo(ddlEmpName.SelectedValue,"","");
        DisplayDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo);
        if (ddlStatus.SelectedValue != "0")
            EnableDeviceInfo(false);
        else
            EnableDeviceInfo(true); //only enables on second call ???
        tbEmpName.Text = "";
    }

    protected void EnableDeviceInfo(bool enabled)
    {
        cbIMEI.Enabled = enabled;
        cbPhoneNumber.Enabled = enabled;
        rblCarrier_SP.Enabled = enabled;
        ddlModel.Enabled = enabled;
        rblSize.Enabled = enabled;
        rblColor_SP.Enabled = enabled;
        tbAssignedDate.Enabled = enabled;
        ddlScenario.Enabled = enabled;
        rblSplitBilling.Enabled = enabled;
        rblPhoneCombined_SP.Enabled = enabled;
        tbComments.Enabled = enabled;
        btnSubmit.Enabled = enabled;
    }
```

The aspx control that calls FindEmpInfo is ddlEmpName:

```
<asp:TableCell runat="server" >
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Employee Name: " Font-Bold="true" />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEmpName" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FindEmpInfo" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </asp:TableCell>
```

and the ComboBox looks like this:

```
<asp:TableCell ID="TableCell3" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="IMEI: " Font-Bold="true" />
                        <asp:ComboBox ID="cbIMEI" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ChangeDataForIMEI" AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:ComboBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
```

This works fine, except that the ComboBox's status doesn't become enabled the first time EnableDeviceInfo is called with its parameter set to true. It takes two calls to enable the ComboBox. However, if the parameter is false, it works the first time. I've run this code through the debugger, and the parameter is always set to the correct value, and I see the Enabled property set correctly, but on the first pass it always remains grayed out if the parameter is true. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Can you post the ASPX (or at least the portion of the ASPX involved) as well.

Comment: I've added the relevant ASPX code to my question, CodingGorilla.

Comment: I assume there's an `UpdatePanel` somewhere?  When you say you see the `Enabled` property set correctly, I assume you're inspecting this on the server side?  Have you tried running a javascript debugger to see what the client side code is doing?

Comment: No, there's no UpdatePanel. I'm inspecting the Enabled property on each control in the EnableDeviceInfo method (server side). I'm using VisualStudio, so I've used the debugger to also move through the javascript code on the page, but I don't see anything relevant. Perhaps a different debugger would be more informative for the client side?

Comment: It's been a while since I used ASP.NET Ajax, but without an `UpdatePanel` then the only way for the state of the controls to change is a full page render (I.E. a full post-back).  You say that the second time around it enables the controls, is that during a full postback?

Comment: No, I just change the SelectedIndex of ddlEmpName a second time. It always works for enabled = false (first and second time), but setting enabled = true requires a second attempt. ddlEmpName has AutoPostBack set to true, so I believe it always calls a full post-back anyway.

Comment: So where does the AJAX part come in?  I'm thinking this is an order of events thing, but without a lot more of the code it's going to be really hard to pinpoint.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond; I've been on vacation. The cbIMEI ComboBox is an AJAX control. The only other code I'm aware of that's necessary is the registration of the AjaxControlToolkit assembly at the top of the page, and an asp:ScriptManager, also at the top of the page. Other pages I've got with Ajax controls work fine set up this way. Is there something else I need specifically with a ComboBox?